# How to install a old ebuild while it's no longer in the portage tree? For example, subversion 1.4.4

Tags: package-management, gentoo, downgrade

For compatibility reasons, I want to install `subversion-1.4.4-r4` rather than the latest.

Answer (score 9):

As webdestroya said, you'll need to find the old ebuild and put it in an overlay. The first part of that is easy enough, since the Portage tree is stored in a CVS repository which is [browsable online](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/) (you can also [check out a copy](http://anoncvs.gentoo.org/) if you want, although to get just one ebuild that's unnecessary). Here's a direct link to the [`dev-util/subversion` folder](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/dev-util/subversion/?hideattic=0) which will show you ebuilds for all versions of Subversion going back to... well, far earlier than you need.

Once you get the ebuild, you should put it into a local overlay, which is also reasonably easy. If you already have a local overlay you know how to do this ;-) but if not: Create the directory `/usr/local/portage/dev-util/subversion`. Within it you'll need to set up the following structure:

```
subversion/
 |- subversion-1.4.4-r4.ebuild
 |- files/
    |- subversion-1.4-db4.patch
    |- subversion-1.1.1-perl-vendor.patch
    |- subversion-hotbackup-config.patch
    |- subversion-1.3.1-neon-config.patch
    |- subversion-apr_cppflags.patch
    |- subversion-1.4.3-debug-config.patch
    |- subversion-1.4.3-neon-0.26.3.patch
```

where all the files should be downloaded from the CVS repository's web interface. Once you have the files in place, run

```
ebuild /usr/local/portage/dev-util/subversion/subversion-1.4.4-r4.ebuild manifest
```

which will create the manifest file that lists checksums and file sizes for the ebuild, the patches, and the source archive. (If this were a more recent ebuild, you'd be able to download the manifest from the CVS repository, but back when this ebuild was current, Portage used a different system for checking file integrity.)

Finally, once the files are in place, add the line

```
PORTDIR_OVERLAY="/usr/local/portage"
```

to your `make.conf`. You should then be able to `emerge =dev-util/subversion-1.4.4-r4`. No guarantee that the compilation will succeed, though...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install something that is not in the portage tree, you will have to find/create the ebuild yourself.

From there you can add it into the tree and install it.

Comment: Modifying the tree is a bad idea, creating a local overlay is simpler.